# Unable to understand a html attribute

Tags: html, action

I am learning html from [w3schools](http://w3schools.com). They have used `<form action="demo_form.asp">` this `form` tag with attribute `action="demo_form.asp`. I know the meaning of **form** tag as well as **action** attribute. But I don't know what is the meaning of `action="demo_form.asp"`. When I use this attribute `action="demo_form.asp"`, a file named **demo_form.asp** start downloading!

Can anybody explain me this thing?

Full code is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_color).

Comment: The action attribute defines, to which page your form data is submitted. If the page demo_form.asp is getting downloaded, either there is a error(s) in the page or your server is mis-configured.

Comment: Can you tell me where is the error? And I have tried this code in my computers editor.

Comment: There is no error. You specified that when your form is submitted, you want the file `demo_form.asp` to be responsible for handling the request. Thats what this attribute specifies. If you want the form to submit to the same page, just don't set any `action` attribute.

Comment: I am not understanding why `demo_form.asp` file is started downloading and why the file is completely empty??

Comment: I tried the example in w3schools. It didn't start downloading the file, instead it shown me another page which had the value i entered in the form.

Comment: @mohamedrias, Have you tried it in your own editor?

Comment: Yes, i tried it in my local editor. It took me to this page local_path/demo_form.asp?favcolor=rias

Comment: @Scotia웃 Mostly it must give you "This webpage is not found" error if you are trying it in your local. Because you don't have the page (demo_form.asp)specified in the action attribute. May be you can open that file and check what content it has. It should have "This webpage is not found" error only inside

Comment: @mohamedrias  Then I don't know why it is happening to me!

Comment: I guess you are not running a server. ASP requires IIS as a server to run. Do you have installed any such?

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS No. I am not!

Comment: Yeah that is the point. ASP or PHP requires a server to run. So decide your platform, whether ASP or PHP. If you go with ASP install IIS. If you decide PHP, install APACHE and PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[From HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)**

```
action = uri [CT]
This attribute specifies a form processing agent.
```

It's used to send the request to the page (url) specified in the action attribute when the form is submitted.

As per the example:

Once you enter your favourite color in the input box & click submit.

The form details is sent to the server page (demo_form.jsp) based on form action.

There the form is processed and based on the input, it's redirecting you to different page.

Where you can find the fav color which you have entered is mentioned there.

```
Input was received as:

favcolor=blue
```

Answer (score 1):

`action` attribute define the page to be use to post the data, when you hit submit button it redirect to the page you have mentioned in the `action` attribute. so that you can access the data submitted through this page.

Answer (score 1):

The `action="demo_form.asp"` attribute is the file to which your `<form>` will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `action` attribute tells the browser the location of the script that will process this form. In the example you have provided, the data submitted by the user in the form will be processed by the file/script called `demo_form.asp`.

Answer (score 0):

The `action` element points to a thing that will handle the content of the form you have submitted.  This can be as simple as a new page (maybe php), or a .cgi script, and so on.  In your case it is attempting to submit to an ASP page.  If you are attempting to use the form in your own pages, it is likely your browser can't find 'demo_form.asp'.

Why it is attempting to download it, rather than just tell you the page is missing, I'm afraid I don't know.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

demo_form.asp should execute and not download. How are you running the file? It looks like your IIS is not enabled.

If you are trying this locally, to run ASP you'll have to configure IIS in your system (it is not enabled by default) and then use

> ```
> http://localhost
> ```

.... to run your file. Otherwise ASP will not execute. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for enabling IIS. Once IIS is enabled,

> ```
> http://localhost
> ```

will point to c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder by default. Create a folder in wwroot (say test) and place your files inside that folder. If your file is abc.asp then to run it you'll have to type

> ```
> http://localhost/test/abc.asp
> ```

.

Hope this helps.